# Removing empty fields from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Normally you would use the following to remove a field from a collection. However the code below does not work for empty (`""`) fields. How would you go about deleting an empty field in MongoDB?

```
db.collection.update({}, {$unset: {"": ""}}, {multi:true})
```

I get the following error message when I try this:

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 56,
        "errmsg" : "An empty update path is not valid."
    }
})
```

Comment: How are you defining an "empty field" in your question?  Can you edit your question to provide an example?

Comment: The key is literally ""

Comment: Interesting...I didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: I believe this is the relevant bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12996

Comment: I have the exact same problem. How was this solved? The accepted answer does not work in latest MongoDB

Comment: The problem occurred in mongodb 2.6. What it's like in 3.0 and above I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like empty string keys must only be partially supported by MongoDB.

This isn't as efficient as a multi-update, but it does work to remove those fields in the shell:

```js
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    delete doc[''];
    db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

To do this using the **update** or **updateMany** method, you must specify the parameter you want to update, such as `name`:

```
db.collection.updateMany({name: ""}, { $unset : { name : 1 }})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to delete rows with the field, that is empty, you can use:

```
db.collection.deleteMany({ 'myField': null})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for mongodb version 4.2+**
(db.collection.save is no longer supported)

Empty field keys aren't fully supported by mongodb, and look like they are going to be [depreciated](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6852).

To get rid of empty field keys

```
db.collection.find({"":{$exists:true}).forEach(
    (doc)=>{
       delete doc[""];  
       db.collection.replaceOne(doc,doc,{upsert:true})
})
```